# Ambiguous match found exception in using Moq-Mock library

Tags: c#, inheritance, mocking, moq, ambiguous

I am using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and I realize In this situation I got the  `Ambiguous match found` exception that I need help:

Here is my models:

```
public class User
{
}

public class CustomUser
{
}
```

Some classes:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class Father : BaseClass
{
    public virtual new CustomUser User { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Father
{
}
```

And finally:

```
void Main()
{
    var user = new Mock<CustomUser>();
    var child = new Mock<Child>();
    child.SetupGet(x=>x.User).Returns (user.Object);  // Ambiguous match found.
}
```

---

**Update:**
Why am I using this?!
Because I'm coding `MVC-WebAPI` and I have a `BaseController` which inherits the `ApiController`.
OK, in the `ApiController` we have a `IPrincipal User` property that I overrided it with my `ICustomPrinciple` implementation ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)).
Now I want to mock for example `ProductController : BaseController`.

```
var controller = new Mock<ProductController>();
var user = new Mock<CustomPrincipal>();

user.SetupGet(x => x.FullName).Returns("some full name");

controller.SetupGet(x => x.UserRoleID).Returns(81);// UserRoleID is getter and I do some stuff here.
controller.SetupGet(x => x.User).Returns(user.Object);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The classes show poor design that leads me to believe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why is `Father` changing the base property? (explain so I can better understand what you are trying to do). Difficulty with testing something usually signals a problem with the original design

Comment: @Nkosi post updated.

Comment: There should be no need to ever mock a controller. What are you actually trying to achieve? You should be able to create an instance of the controller and set the User.

Comment: @Nkosi if I have a `getter` property that gets some data from request or ther sources, then I have more issues.

Comment: Which is why you should show us what you are actually trying to do so we understand the actual problem.

Comment: @Nkosi I didn't know `why am I using this` is important and I was avoiding to write not necessary codes, BTW I updated the post again. thanks.

Comment: I gave a similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41589044/5233410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mock to work it needs `virtual` property that in case of inheritance  doesn't exist in base class (no ambiguity)

So you could rename the property as Rahul suggested or change the `BaseClass` to contain generic property:

```
public class BaseClass<TUser>
{
    public virtual TUser User { get; set; }
}

public class Father : BaseClass<CustomUser>
{
}

...
child.SetupGet(x=>x.User).Returns (user.Object);  // Works!
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are changing or forcefully hiding the base type and that's the issue here. If you want to define a separate member returning separate type then do it so like below and now your mock shouldn't complain anything when you say `child.SetupGet(x => x.User1).Returns(user.Object);`. You are changing the type of the property from `User` to `Customuser` and those two entities have no similarity between them.

```
public class Father : BaseClass
{
    public virtual CustomUser User1 { get; set; }
}
```